# Elasticsearch shutdown crash when run as Windows service

Tags: elasticsearch

Whenever I stop the Elasticsearch service, the following Application Error is logged in the Windows event log indicating an access violation in Java. There are no errors in the Elasticsearch log files. This occurs on multiple machines running Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-bit, and occurs with Elasticseach versions 1.3.4 and 1.4.4. I have also tried multiple versions of the Java SDK (8 updates 25 and 40, 7 updates 55 and 71) all with the same result. There is only one node.

```
Faulting application name: elasticsearch-service-x64.exe, version: 1.0.15.0, time stamp: 0x51543b9d
Faulting module name: jvm.dll, version: 25.40.0.25, time stamp: 0x54daf724
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000213388
Faulting process id: 0x2f0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d05a7ef40ebb59
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\ELK\Elasticsearch\bin\elasticsearch-service-x64.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
Report Id: 6638e03c-c72f-11e4-ae77-782bcb9439d2
```

I installed Elasticsearch as a Windows service using the service.bat file provided in the bin folder. If I run elasticsearch.bat in a command prompt instead of as a service and stop it via ctrl-c, then the shutdown error does not occur. Since I need to run Elasticsearch as a service, does anyone know how to prevent this crash from occurring on every shutdown?

Comment: Hi ruthiefa, have you been able to find a solution? I am experiencing the same crash.

Comment: No, the crash still occurs on every shutdown. Even if this error doesn't effect the Elasticsearch data, it is a bad thing to have such frequent Application Errors. Just noticed that Elasticsearch 1.5 was released on March 23, maybe this will help, but the release notes don't indicate anything.

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing the same crash also with version 2.1. Anything new there?

Comment: No, nothing new as I've had to leave this project for many months. Sorry to hear it's still in version 2.1.